# Very slow SQL query when using IP in connection string

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am having a real big headache with slow SQL query. I have two connection string which are as follows :

```
ConnectString1 = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=MSSQLSERVER5;Database=SchoolMain;Uid=Admin;Pwd=admin101;"
```

and

```
ConnectString2 = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=Admin;Password=admin101;Initial Catalog=SchoolMain;Data Source=192.168.1.2,1433"
```

Both are connecting to a SQL Server database instance on the same system. The first connects using the database instance name, while second connects using IP address (over the internet to the system) and port number.

The query with `ConnectString1` is very first, takes less than 2 seconds to execute while query using `ConnectString2` is extremely very slow and most times comes back with timeout expired error.

I have searched everywhere on the internet and still cannot find where the issue is. I read about turning off the LLMNR protocol and adding entries in the hosts file to tackle Reverse DNS, followed the steps but it's still the same as query with `ConnectString2` is still very slow.

Though when I changed the IP address in `ConnectString2` from `192.168.1.2` to `127.0.0.1`, the query works very fast, just exactly as it is with `ConnectString1`.

Is there a way to route all IP address to 127.0.0.1 on the machine?

I need `ConnectString2` to work query will be pushed over the IP address from other systems outside the LAN.

Note: I am using SQL Server 2008

Please help.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 reached end of life well over a year ago and are now **completely unsupported**. You really should be looking at upgrading to a supported version.

Comment: If it's on the same machine you should not use TCP at all. Instead just use a `.` so you have `Data Source=.`. Then it will use Shared Memory which is quite a bit faster

Answer (score 1):

The main reason this may happen is reverse DNS, meaning the sql needs to translate the IP to a physical address and it takes time.

To fix this problem use your host file to add the address to your machine and than use the name given at the host file instead of the IP.

If you do not want to temper with the host file try to look at the [alternate solution](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/oct/26/sql-server-slow-connections-with-2-second-or-so-delay) to enable the TCP/IP which is disabled by default.

Comment: Thanks....
Please how exactly can i fix this using my host file ? TCP/IP is enabled on my dbase all these while.
I need help on how to update the host file to resolve this.

Comment: Add the address to your host file and use the alias in the file for the connection, simple really :)

Comment: i really don't know how to do this. I have been able to locate and open the host file using notepad, but what exact lines to i add ? Using my live case as shown in the post ?
I added :
127.0.0.1 192.168.1.2
but nothing changed, so i guess i am doing something wrong.

Comment: I looked up, added the address to the host file like this : 
192.168.1.2 MSSQLSERVER5 and saved it. I tried the connection ConnectString2 again using IP address and there is no changes. Query and Connection still very slow or time out. I don't know what else to do.